# django cms - resolving pages url by slug

Tags: django, django-views, django-cms

Is it possible to resolve a page url by its slug?
Something like:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
reverse('pages-details-by-slug',{slug:'my-page-slug'})
```

But I got:

```
NameError: name 'slug' is not defined
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is not Javascript; dictionary keys need to be quoted.

```
reverse('pages-details-by-slug', {'slug': 'my-page-slug'})
```

Comment: For Django 1.9, use `reverse('page-details-by-slug', kwargs={'slug': my-page-slug})`

Comment: That `kwargs` in there is important :)

Answer (score 3):

solved:

```
try:
    from cms.models import Title
    page = Title.objects.get(slug="my-page-slug").page
    return page.get_absolute_url()
except Title.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Comment: If using draft/published versions of pages, it's worth bearing in mind that **two** objects may be returned to the  `page` object above.

Probably worth bearing in mind whether you want published and/or draft versions.

Comment: For the published/draft case you could do `page = Title.objects.get(slug='my-page-slug', page__publisher_is_draft=False).page` (Tested on Django CMS 2.4)